# Cannot assign value of type 'TLPHAsset' to type 'UIImage?'

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/tilltue/TLPhotoPicker/blob/master/Images/custom_cameracell.gif)
in my project. But when I am trying to add the selected images to my collectionView it's giving an error like

> "Cannot assign value of type 'TLPHAsset' to type 'UIImage?'"

at the line of "

`cell.pic.image = selectedAssets[indexPath.item]`

Can anyone help me to solve this.Thankyou.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : GalleryCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GalleryCollectionViewCell
        cell.pic.image = selectedAssets[indexPath.item]
       // cell.pic.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectedAssets is any array of type `TLPHAsset`, so if you need to assign image, you need to use `fullResolutionImage` property.

```
let asset: TLPHAsset = selectedAssets[indexPath.item]
if let image = asset.fullResolutionImage {
     cell.pic.image = image
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you but Please if you have spare time can I ask one question related to `TLPhotoPicker` actually I haven't found any information.